# Azure App Insights show space consuming metrics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I got alerts that my daily 1GB limit app insight data volume is exceeded. How can I figure out what entries are consuming the most space?

The graph under `app insights -> Usage and estimated costs` shows me a summary, but I can't drill down.

I couldn't find any property of log/trace entries that gives me the size.

- Is there any?
- Which entries are accumulated in the "metric" category?
- Can I somehow get the query, that generates this chart?

[image: data volume trends]

Comment: That's odd. Can you provide more information about your scenario? Are you monitoring a webapp, if not, what else? Is you webapp running on IIS or in Azure App Service? How many requests does your webapp receive every day? 
I have a webapp generating ~400MB/day but the "metric" part is Epsilon. 
You can query gathered metrics under "Logs" with by just writing "customMetrics" in the query field, how many results do you get for the past 24h? I get about 500.

Comment: We monitor a service fabric cluster (~20 services (one of them a web API), 5 Actor types) Datafactory, IoT Hub, and more services. But it is our dev environment, that is basically not under heavy load (5 developers). `customMetrics | summarize count()` gives me 1,089,247 entries for the last 24h. I think this is something ^^

Comment: Not familiar with service fabric but it seems to me that you have more than enough information in 'customMetrics' rows to find the culprit :) Good luck!

Comment: @ThibaultD. it contains mostly performance counters of the cluster. Thanks for the hint we will have a look into reducing the sampling rate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a hidden field `_BilledSize`, you can check the size of each log entry by using it, example as below:

[image]

or using summarize operator:

[image]

or in azure portal -> click on "Metrics" menu for more details:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was searching for!